# How does an MLlib Estimator know what are the features and target columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I try to follow this [MLlib tutorial](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html). I understood the concept of Estimators. It takes a data-frame as an input and uses it to train and return a predictive model which is an Transformer in MLlib terminology (something that takes a data-frame as an input and returns another data-frame).

What is not clear to me is how does an Estimator knows what columns of the data-frame should be treated as features and what column should be taken as target.

Let's take a look at this example:

```py
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

# Prepare training data from a list of (label, features) tuples.
training = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.1, 0.1])),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.0, -1.0])),
    (0.0, Vectors.dense([2.0, 1.3, 1.0])),
    (1.0, Vectors.dense([0.0, 1.2, -0.5]))], ["label", "features"])

# Create a LogisticRegression instance. This instance is an Estimator.
lr = LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01)
# Print out the parameters, documentation, and any default values.
print("LogisticRegression parameters:\n" + lr.explainParams() + "\n")

# Learn a LogisticRegression model. This uses the parameters stored in lr.
model1 = lr.fit(training)
```

I guess that the model takes the `features` column as features and treats the `label` column as target. Is it correct? If it is the case, can this default behavior be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LogisticRegression` had [`labelCol`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=logisticregression#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.labelCol) and [`featuresCol`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=logisticregression#pyspark.ml.classification.LogisticRegression.featuresCol) `Params` which by default are `lablel` and `features`. Both can be set in the constructor

```py
LogisticRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.01, labelCol="foo", featuresCol="bar")
```

or using corresponding setter methods:

```py
lr.setLabelCol("foo").setFeaturesCol("bar")
```

The same `Params` are used with majority of `ml` classification and prediction algorithms.